# Sql Server report parameter resets back to single selection

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In one of the reports if I do a '(Select All)' on the multi select parameter and then run the report or select any other dropdown parameter it resets the last dropdown parameter to a single selection.

My question is why does it do that and how to enforce the last selection, which in my case is Select All.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem on a number of times.  In my situation, it ended up being that either the value or the label had bad data in it, typically it was an ASCII 10 character (hard return) at the end of it. By cleaning up the data it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

this can happen only if one parameter depends on another.
You can use: Report parameters "advanced" properties and set: Refresh data when parameter changes: Never refresh

Comment: thanks for trying but this didn't fix it. As soon as I run the report the parameter dropdown box resets and selecting only one item in the list. Also as soon as I even click on any other dropdown parameter it resets. No matter what I do it always select that one specifit item in the list. Which is not even the first one.